# Several buttons with same action targeting different divs, compress

Tags: jquery, onclick, targets, simplification

I have a site that will showcase some singers, I have set it up so that when you click on their portrait, a div slides over and starts playing a video. There are five artist with each its own video.

So my question is this, I have several buttons, with separate targets but performing the same action. I have set it up quite rudimentary, with my very limited jQuery skills. What I want to know if there is a better way of doing this?

link to the site (seduction.begop.webfactional.com)

```
//This is the controlls for the first (Babushka)video
var babushkavideo = document.getElementById('vid-babushka');
var playButton = document.getElementById('btn-babushka');
playButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
    babushkavideo.play();
});

var stopButton = document.getElementById('cancel');
stopButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
    babushkavideo.pause();

});


//This is the controllers for the second (Transformer)video
var transformervideo = document.getElementById('vid-transformer');
var playButton = document.getElementById('btn-transformer');
playButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
    transformervideo.play();
});

var stopButton = document.getElementById('cancel2');
stopButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
    transformervideo.pause();
});

//This is the controllers for the third (Puppet)video
var puppetvideo = document.getElementById('vid-puppet');
var playButton = document.getElementById('btn-puppet');
playButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
    puppetvideo.play();
});

var stopButton = document.getElementById('cancel3');
stopButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
    puppetvideo.pause();
});

//This is the controllers for the fourth (Snow Globe)video
var snowglobevideo = document.getElementById('vid-snow-globe');
var playButton = document.getElementById('btn-snow-globe');
playButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
    snowglobevideo.play();
});

var stopButton = document.getElementById('cancel4');
stopButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
    snowglobevideo.pause();
});

//This is the controllers for the third (Cuckoo Clock)video
var cuckooclockvideo = document.getElementById('vid-cuckoo-clock');
var playButton = document.getElementById('btn-cuckoo-clock');
playButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
    cuckooclockvideo.play();
});

var stopButton = document.getElementById('cancel5');
stopButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
    cuckooclockvideo.pause();
});
```

And this part.

```
$('#btn-babushka').click(function(){
    $('#babushka').addClass('panel2')   
});

$('#btn-transformer').click(function(){
    $('#transformer').addClass('panel2')
});

$('#btn-puppet').click(function(){
    $('#puppet').addClass('panel2')
});

$('#btn-snow-globe').click(function(){
    $('#snow-globe').addClass('panel2')
});

$('#btn-cuckoo-clock').click(function(){
    $('#cuckoo-clock').addClass('panel2')
});


$('#cancel').click(function(){
    $('#babushka').removeClass('panel2')
});

$('#cancel2').click(function(){
    $('#transformer').removeClass('panel2')
});

$('#cancel3').click(function(){
    $('#puppet').removeClass('panel2')
});

$('#cancel4').click(function(){
    $('#snow-globe').removeClass('panel2')
});

$('#cancel5').click(function(){
    $('#cuckoo-clock').removeClass('panel2')
});


});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what the question but if you want to reduce the length of the `jQuery` code snippet you provided, I'd suggest you to change the selector to something that selects all buttons in a specific criteria. It could be a css class that doesn't necessarily adds any css style or even better a custom data attribute that can be used with unobtrusive javascript code...for example suppose you have the following buttons

```
<input id='btnOk1' type='button' data-field='ok' data-target='transformer' />
<input id='btnOk2' type='button' data-field='ok' data-target='babushka' />
<input id='btnOk3' type='button' data-field='ok' data-target='puppet' />

<input id='btnCancel1' type='button' data-field='cancel'  data-target='transformer'/>
<input id='btnCancel2' type='button' data-field='cancel' data-target='babushka' />
<input id='btnCancel3' type='button' data-field='cancel' data-target='puppet' />
```

notice that I added a `data-field` attribute in order to group the "types" of buttons, this could be whatever you want, it's mere purpose is to group them so it's easier to identify the buttons in a specific group, which obviously will have a different behaviour, and I also added the `data-target` attribute in order to define which element will be target when adding/removing css classes. Then, hook the onclick event for each button group...

```
$(function(){
    $('[data-field=ok]').click(function(){
         var target = $(this).data('target');
         $('#' + target).addClass('panel2');
    });


    $('[data-field=cancel]').click(function(){
         var target = $(this).data('target');
         $('#' + target).removeClass('panel2');
    });
});
```

And here's a [JS FIDDLER EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k4jwn7j8/)